# Android parse push notification and new GCM generate wrong device token and parse push notification not working

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

**Brief** : In parse installation table device token is not added properly when I use new **GCM API**.
right now following type of device token added into Parse installation table.

**DeviceToken : |ID|1|:crGctxOB068:APA91bFgPRehabJcm9CYdS948iqX2_ppLj02CtbzmEHR0cfbuPooq5F--hqqvR9AH-Ez6MWMQON1Toc2DiNJTNdpRc3nmm3ukIpWJ1jHaXq0Iug6MoHbmKb9U0ak2CrKznkpKnPY5_Jp**

---

**Detailed description** :

I have used new **GCM api** to get registration id. 
I need that **regId** for internal use.

I have used code from following link of google: [Google cloud messaging android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client).

I have noted one point. when ever I start app parse get deviceToken properly. After login I am updating "user" field using following code in **onCreate** of mainActivity

```
 ParseACL acl = new ParseACL();
 acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
 acl.setPublicWriteAccess(true);

 ParseInstallation installation =     ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    installation.setACL(acl);

    if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        installation.put("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    }
 installation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.e("installation", "success");
                Log.i("parse", "token after save : " + ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getString("deviceToken"));
                ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {

                        if (e != null) {

                            Log.e("error: ", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } else {

                            Log.e("subscribed: ", "to broadcast channel");
                            Log.i("parse", "token after subscribe : " + ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getString("deviceToken"));
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Log.e("installation", "failed");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

**Generally when above code run deviceToken got changed to Above mentioned token which seems wrong. So My push notification is not working.**

Comment: How do you verify is the deviceToken got changed and is wrong

Comment: when my app run first time I have checked Installation table's deviceToken field it look ok. after login when I save "user" to installation then deviceToken field getting changed to above mentioned token.

Note : sometimes its working fine also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved issue.

I need to pass GCM device token to other webservice so I have used following code to get token from GCM.

```
 InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
               String token = instanceID.getToken(CommonUtils.SENDER_ID,
                       GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

After getting token from this code parse's deviceToken changed.
So instead of using above code I have used following code to get deviceToken and it solved the issue.

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getString("deviceToken");
```